# parse xml file in Java with DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I would like to parse this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="descripciones">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

The original file is a much bigger array.
Here is my code:

```
builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("descripciones.xml"));
Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("string-array");

Element nl1 =(Element) nl.item(0);
NodeList nl2=nl1.getChildNodes();

for(int i=0; i<nl2.getLength();i++){
    String text=nl2.item(i).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(i+text);
}
```

The problem is when I print the result I get every each line I get an empty item:

```
1 one
2
3 two
4
```

Is there a way to fix it? Is there a better way to extract the data between  tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handling ALL the child nodes of `string-array`, including the text nodes before and after the `item` nodes.  Try

```
int pos = 0;
for(int i=0; i<nl2.getLength();i++){
    Node n = nl2.item(i);
    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        pos++;
        String text=n.getTextContent();
        System.out.println(pos + text);
    }
}
```

This will skip non-Element children of `string-array`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a trim() on getTextContent() e.g.

```
String text=nl2.item(i).getTextContent().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl2.getLength(); i++) {
     Node nt = nl2.item(i);
     if (nt.getFirstChild() != null) {
         String text = nt.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
         System.out.println(text);
     }
}
```